# print the line if the first column of the current and last line are different

Tags: awk

I need to print the lines whose first column's value is different from the last rows first column's value.

Example:

```
1 one                    line number1
1 one one one            line number2
2 two two                line number3
2 two two two            line number4
2 two two two            line number5
2 two two two two        line number6
2 two two two two two    line number7
3 three                  line number8
3 three three            line number9
4 four                   line number10
5 five                   line number11
5 five five five         line number12
5 five five              line number13
6 six                    line number14
6 six six                line number15
6 six                    line number16
6 six                    line number17
```

I needed following result, as this represents the rows which have different 1st columns if compared to last rows first column.

```
1 one one one            line number2
2 two two                line number3
2 two two two two two    line number7
3 three                  line number8
3 three three            line number9
4 four                   line number10
5 five                   line number11
5 five five              line number13
6 six                    line number14
```

I tried following command but its not helping.

```
echo "$x" |awk '{t=$1;line=$0;next} $1!=t{print line ORS $0}'
```

Comment: I think your question is not clear, really, personally I dont understand what you want to achieve, and I dont understand example provided

Comment: Hello,  I have changed the example input and output to put clearer picture.  Here, I need to get the lines whose first column's value is not same as the first column's value of last row. For example:  Line 2 and line 3 have different first col value so printed in result...

Comment: Column `6` appears to match your cryptic requirement. Why is it in the output?

Comment: why is line 3 printed?  It has the same value as line 4.

Comment: I am completely baffled by the logic. I cannot find any in your example input and example output. Your explanation in the question and comment is completely ununderstandable. Could you please rephrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this will work, but I found your logic very hard to follow...

```
$ awk 'p && p!=$1 {if(!a[NR-1]) print prev; print; a[NR]++} 
                  {p=$1; prev=$0}' file

1 one one one            line number2
2 two two                line number3
2 two two two two two    line number7
3 three                  line number8
3 three three            line number9
4 four                   line number10
5 five                   line number11
5 five five              line number13
6 six                    line number14
```

Comment: Thanks for Understanding the problem statement